# Azure AD B2C - Cannot get customClaim (sid) to show in JWT (Revised: Add sid claim to Built-In User Flow)

Tags: azure-active-directory

I have created an Azure B2C app and utilized a built-in sign-in flow which is working great.

I cannot for the life of me get the sid and ipaddrclaim to come across in the JWT idToken. In the azure portal I don't have an option to do "token configuration" as is mentioned in the documentation so I added the following to my manifest file.

Still doesn't work... I'm thinking maybe the built-in flow claims are overwriting the application claims but I don't understand how to get these claims using the built-in flow.

Any help would be appreciated.

```html
"optionalClaims": {
        "idToken": [
            {
                "name": "sid",
                "source": null,
                "essential": true,
                "additionalProperties": []
            },
            {
                "name": "ipaddr",
                "source": null,
                "essential": true,
                "additionalProperties": []
            }
        ],
        "accessToken": [],
        "saml2Token": []
    },
```

Comment: I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/app-registrations-training-guide#features-not-applicable-in-azure-ad-b2c-tenants) documentation stating that token configuration is not available for azure b2c apps. This confirms that the sid claim must be added to the userflow but no idea on how to do that.

Comment: Update... I went down the rabbit hole of trying to creat a custom policy but sid does not appear to be an available optionalClaim. Not sure how to proceed from here.